# Interpretation of conditional Granger results

Tags: interpretation, granger-causality, conditional

I have a question about the `Granger` package.
How are the numbers obtained in the frequency and causal output of the conditional Grangers interpreted?
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: I have provided an answer regarding the interpretation for conditional Granger causality. Regarding *frequency*, please consult the documentation. (It is not clear what *Granger package* you have in mind.)

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I interpret this as follows: given the historal values of $x$, $y$ and $z$, we ask whether including the history of $y$ in addition to the histories of $x$ and $z$ help in predicting $x$ (make the predictions more accurate) compared to not including the history of $y$. If so, $y$ can be said to Granger-cause $x$ conditional on $z$. Otherwise, $y$ can be said to not Granger-cause $x$ conditional on $z$.